# How to pass viewstate with generic values into datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
List< ABC > lstABC = new List< Abc >();//MyList
ViewState["Test"] = lstAbc;    //passed to viewstate 
Datatable dt = (Datatable)ViewState["Test"]; // but datatable Not accepting viewstate with binded list values.
```

Comment: first assign it to List and then explorer how can you convert list to datatable

Comment: Try refer to this https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/converting-generic-list-into-datatable  .  Simply passes in the list as a parm to a datatable method and it will create your datatable, then you can add that to viewstate if needed.

Comment: You can't just cast a list to a data table - so you have to adopt something a per the answer given here.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a datatable

`DataTable DT = new DataTable();`

2)add columns to that Datatable

```
DT.Columns.Add("columnname1", typeof(DateTime));
DT.Columns.Add("columnname2", typeof(String));
```

3. add the rows to that Datatable

   DT.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now, "someString"); //repeat for more rows
4. store the dataTable in the viewstate
   Viewstate["VSDT"] = DT;

5)Where you want to call that DataTable
Create a new DT

```
DataTable NewDT= new DataTable();
NewDT= (DataTable)ViewState["VSDT"];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first make sure the class of the object you are passing in the ViewState is serializable

```
[Serializable]
public class ABC
```

Then, as toly P said, you want to create your datatable, instantiate the columns and add rows. For this you could either use your object type (example 1), or you could  use every parameter inside of it.. let's say an id (int) and a name (string) (example 2)

Example 1:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName1", typeof(ABC)));
foreach(var item in ViewState["Test"] as List<ABC>)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item)
}
```

Example 2:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName1", typeof(int)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ColumnName2", typeof(string)));
foreach(var item in ViewState["Test"] as List<ABC>)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(item.id, item.name)
}
```

You don't want to store the datatable in the ViewState because it isn't serializable. Instead, you store the list and instantiate the DataTable on each load.